# How to get the full call stack-trace in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, stack-trace

I am new to IntelliJ. I am using Apache-Derby db and I want to find out the stack trace (i.e. all the methods called during the execution) for simple JDBC program which connects to db and executes a select query. Can anyone help me?

Comment: here you have very informative article about debugging application in Intellij:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-your-first-java-application.html

Answer (score 0):

At the place where the query is created or any point of your interest,Create an object of Exception and print the stack trace. You can call one of the below methods

```
Exception ex = new Exception();

        ex.getStackTrace()
        ex.printStackTrace()
```

Comment: @Vindod_Jayachandran If I fix a breakpoint at executeQuery line in the code and after executing line and I want to know using the IDE the list of methods called by the program

Comment: if you are able to set break point, then when code stops in break point, your debug windown in intellij idea will show complete call stack trace.

Comment: I need to use the step-into button to get the complete call stack trace. Can you tell how to get the list of methods?